# end points for calendar as PDF in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Anyone know how to make an end points request(backend) creating a school calendar as a PDF in Django REST Framework?

I don't know what to do when comes to generate a PDF.

Comment: Add more detail please. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all django does not have built pdf response so you shall use a differnt tool like repotlab. Check the code and explanation below:

Write your view
The key to generating PDFs dynamically with Django is that the ReportLab API acts on file-like objects, and Django’s FileResponse objects accept file-like objects.

Here’s a “Hello World” example:

```
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def some_view(request):
    # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()

    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

The code and comments should be self-explanatory, but a few things deserve a mention:

The response will automatically set the MIME type application/pdf based on the filename extension. This tells browsers that the document is a PDF file, rather than an HTML file or a generic application/octet-stream binary content.
When as_attachment=True is passed to FileResponse, it sets the appropriate Content-Disposition header and that tells web browsers to pop-up a dialog box prompting/confirming how to handle the document even if a default is set on the machine. If the as_attachment parameter is omitted, browsers will handle the PDF using whatever program/plugin they’ve been configured to use for PDFs.
You can provide an arbitrary filename parameter. It’ll be used by browsers in the “Save as…” dialog.
You can hook into the ReportLab API: The same buffer passed as the first argument to canvas.Canvas can be fed to the FileResponse class.
Note that all subsequent PDF-generation methods are called on the PDF object (in this case, p) – not on buffer.
Finally, it’s important to call showPage() and save() on the PDF file.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/outputting-pdf/